# How can I install the MFC Grid control control to toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

[here is it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control). How to add this control to toolbox for using it in dialog visual editor?

Answer (score 1):

That control, as posted in the article, is distributed as source code.  As the article states:

> To use the Grid control in your project you will need to add a number
>   of files to your project

If you want to include it in the toolbox, you should look to convert it into a form that the toolbox understands.  Within Visual Studio, go to *Tools*, *Choose Toolbox Items*.  A dialog should appear listing the types of objects you can import into the toolbox.  You should be able to re-factor the source code from the article to create a custom control that can be [packaged for the toolbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165358(v=vs.100).aspx).  Otherwise, simply choose another alternative control from what's listed in the dialog box (eg. FlexGrid).